Converting old SDEBINARY records to PostGIS geometry
I am trying to recover a project from a now-defunct organization. I don't have access to any Esri products, and I'm trying to convert their data export into a useful format. I was given a PostgreSQL DB that contains many rows that contain a column with text-formatted data that looks like:
8F0000000F00000008001000E6100000B301000001110004A3918BE6C8129AB1AEEAEF18F88E64AD8804C99A3AADAE02E0A004EEC17B8FA611E79256B49505F5D02AAEE807DD901A9EB802D49408B88105D2DF02DD7AE5F108D75FFAF506CB8954CC8540DCE202EAE6608FA0C301F6AD08A68F12BEF2D30380A8D6B907000000000000000000000000000000000000

I had assumed this was hex-representation of WKB, but a little digging tells me this is likely SDEBINARY. All the tooling I see online for converting this datatype assumes you have a live Esri source to copy from, but I'm trying to process this post-mortem. I'm fine with solutions using Python or R or any open source tooling out there.
ETA: I would accept an Esri-based answer because we could buy a seat for it if need be, but how would I even go about converting these text strings back into something Esri understands?

Worst thing about proprietary data types? They're proprietary. I doubt that you will find a working OS tool that successfully reverse-engineered a legacy close-sourced, compressed binary data encoding...
